# AngularJS: Why angular is not binding the word filtered in menu which is outside of ng-view?

Tags: angularjs

I am have a new problem in Angular, I have a menu and a nview. In menu I have the typical options and an input and Filter Button. The menute it is outside of ng div. The view load tables which will be filtered for the searcher of the menu.

the index code as sample is:

```
<div class="capa">    
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>            
            <td colspan="6" style="background-color: white !Important; border: 0;padding:0px;">
                <div ng-include="url" ng-controller="ProductDetailController" ng-init="item = data"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <td class="TableControler" colspan="6">
            <button ng-click="Add();" class="btn btn-primary">
              <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Añadir
            </button>
        </td>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Categoría</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>

        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="product in products | filter: dataService.Palabra" >
            <td><a ng-click="getproduct(product.Id);">{{product.Id}}</a></td>
            <td>{{product.Name}}</td>
            <td class="remarcar">{{product.Category}}</td>
            <td><a ng-click="testprice(product.Id, product.Price);">{{product.Price}}</a></td>
            <td class="td_img mano"><img src="../../../Content/Img/General/lapiz.png" ng-click="Editar(product.Id);" /></td>
            <td class="td_img mano"><img src="../../../Content/Img/General/trash.png" ng-click="Borrar(product.Id);" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

menu code is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- El logotipo y el icono que despliega el menú se agrupan
       para mostrarlos mejor en los dispositivos móviles -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Desplegar navegación</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logotipo</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Agrupar los enlaces de navegación, los formularios y cualquier
       otro elemento que se pueda ocultar al minimizar la barra -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="/menu1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Productos <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a ng-href="index.html#/menu{{getMenu(1)}}">Remarcar Nombre</a></li>
          <li><a ng-href="index.html#/menu{{getMenu(2)}}">Remarcar Categoria</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html#/menu{{getMenu(3)}}">Remarcar Precio</a></li>          
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a ng-href="index.html#/menu{{getMenu(4)}}">Sin Marcas</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="navbar-form navbar-left" >
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="palabra" placeholder="Poner Palabras">
      </div>
      <button ng-click="Filtrar(palabra)" class="btn btn-default">Filtrar</button>
      <button ng-click="Todos()" class="btn btn-primary">Ver Todos</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

controller is:

```
angular.module('productsApp').controller('ProductController', 
    ['$scope', 'dataService', '$location', function ($scope, dataService, $location) {
        $scope.data;
        $scope.visibility = true;
        $scope.menu = "/index.html#/menu4";
        $scope.palabra = "";
        $scope.products = dataService.Palabra;


        $scope.Filtrar = function (palabra) {
            dataService.Palabra = palabra;

            alert(dataService.Palabra);
            dataService.Filtrar(palabra).success(function (resp) {
                $location.path('/menu2').search({dato: JSON.stringify(resp[0].data)});
            });
        }
    }]);

app.js is:

var app = angular.module('productsApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider)
{
    $routeProvide.
        when('/menu1', {
            controller: 'ProductController',
            templateUrl: '/Scripts/App/Html/ProductList1.html'
        }).
        when('/menu2', {
            controller: 'ProductController',
            templateUrl: '/Scripts/App/Html/ProductList2.html'
        }).
        when('/menu3', {
            controller: 'ProductController',
            templateUrl: '/Scripts/App/Html/ProductList3.html'
        }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);
```

when I click in Filtrar, palabra is not assigned in the Partial, which has a table with ng-repeat filtered. The template shows palabra.

the template is:

```
{{palabra}}
<div class="capa">

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>            
            <td colspan="6" style="background-color: white !Important; border: 0;padding:0px;">
                <div ng-include="url" ng-controller="ProductDetailController" ng-init="item = data"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <td class="TableControler" colspan="6">
            <button ng-click="Add();" class="btn btn-primary">
              <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Añadir
            </button>
        </td>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Categoría</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>

        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="product in products | filter: dataService.Palabra" >
            <td><a ng-click="getproduct(product.Id);">{{product.Id}}</a></td>
            <td>{{product.Name}}</td>
            <td class="remarcar">{{product.Category}}</td>
            <td><a ng-click="testprice(product.Id, product.Price);">{{product.Price}}</a></td>
            <td class="td_img mano"><img src="../../../Content/Img/General/lapiz.png" ng-click="Editar(product.Id);" /></td>
            <td class="td_img mano"><img src="../../../Content/Img/General/trash.png" ng-click="Borrar(product.Id);" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Why angular is not binding the word filtered? What I need to add to show in ng-view the word filtered in ng-include?

What I see after click is no action in the filter.

Answer (score 0):

I found after some hours the solution

Inside the controller I added `$scope.word`;

Inside function index, after `ng-view` I added `ng-init="word:palabra"`

In partial list I changed palabra in the repeater to word.

With that changes works.